# failed to asynchronously prepare wasm: RuntimeError: abort(both async and sync fetching of the wasm failed). Build with -s ASSERTIONS=1 for more info

Tags: angular, face-detection, sam, wasm-pack

I am working on angular 12 application and trying to integrate **Innovatrics InnoCameraComponent** to capture image. Application is woking fine with Localhost but when i deploy the Application on IIS with https protocol i am getting error **AutoCaptureError: Cannot init face detector**

[image]

Application is working fine ,opening camera and auto capturing the image but when we publish build on IIS with (ng build --prod) it is giving error

failed to asynchronously prepare wasm: RuntimeError: abort(both async and sync fetching of the wasm failed). Build with -s ASSERTIONS=1 for more info.

Comment: could you solve this error?

Comment: Yes, After upgrading Angular CLI i have faced this issue, now i came back to previous version